# How to parse tokens from a mathematical equation?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a question on parser, whenever a user enters the expression like  `(a+b*c(d-e)`, He forgot to enter the other closing brace, and the program should give an error like `It's a wrong Expression`. Please help me out in doing this program, I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Parse the input, whenever an opening "(" is found, push it on to Stack. Pop Stack if ")" is encountered. After input tokens are all processed, check whether the stack is empty. If empty input is correct, otherwise wrong expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `stack` data structure to validate the parenthesis matching.

If the character is `'(','{','['` **push** the character onto the stack if the character is `')','}',']'` respectively for the matching opening bracket then **pop**. Continue this till the stack is empty.

Code:

```
 import java.util.*;

 class ParenthesisMatching
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stack<Integer> stk = new Stack<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Enter expression");
        String exp = scan.next();        
        if(isValid(exp))
            System.out.println("matched");
        else System.out.println("unmatched");
    }

    public static boolean isValid(String s) {
        HashMap<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
        map.put('(', ')');
        map.put('[', ']');
        map.put('{', '}');

        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char curr = s.charAt(i);

            if (map.keySet().contains(curr)) {
                stack.push(curr);
            } else if (map.values().contains(curr)) {
                if (!stack.empty() && map.get(stack.peek()) == curr) {
                    stack.pop();
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return stack.empty();
    }  
 }
```

Comment: exactly! this is a paranthesis matching problem

Comment: Is there any CODE for it and makes my program run..

Comment: What if a `+` with no second operand is found? Or is that not part of the problem?

Comment: @RachamallaKavyaSri : see updated answer

Comment: @FallAndLearn added exception catching

Comment: Its showing me the Error can't return a value from method whose result type is void.

Comment: see now.. my mistake..was in a little hurry

Comment: tell me if it solved your purpose

Comment: its workingg....but its giving me output like:
Enter expression:
(a*c*d)
unmatched
unmatched
unmatched
unmatched
unmatched
unmatched
matched

Comment: @RachamallaKavyaSri, remove System.out.println("unmatched"); statement from if(stk.isEmpty()) block

Comment: I actually need to enter this in a Window with a Text field Please enter the Expression...If I miss a Closing brace or Opening Brace It should give me a error. String is unmatched.

Comment: I have tested this code..And it is working fine.

Comment: @JavaHopper , There is no change even though i remove the statement.

Comment: @RachamallaKavyaSri : run the updated code. Its working fine for all test cases.

Comment: @FallAndLearn , which is best IDE to test java Program which also includes GUI. In order to run my java code i need a window and a textBox so how can I do It.

Comment: You can use eclipse.

Comment: You can accept my answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: @FallAndLearn, Yup Its working....

Comment: Glad to help. Thanks